# Change ‘Choose an Option’ variation dropdown label in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I try to change the value of "Select a option" to the attributes names. So in a dropdown where you could select the color it should be the name color as the first one. So far it worked with this code snippet

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'cinchws_filter_dropdown_args', 10 );

function cinchws_filter_dropdown_args( $args ) {
    $var_tax = get_taxonomy( $args['attribute'] );
    $args['show_option_none'] = apply_filters( 'the_title', $var_tax->labels->name );
    return $args;
}
```

The Problem that I have now is that it shows "Product Color" or "Product Material", so it adds a product before the attribute value. How can I get only the Attribute Value?

[image: Dropdown field]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `wc_attribute_label()` dedicated function to get the product attribute label name:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_dropdown_variation_args', 10 );
function filter_dropdown_variation_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_option_none'] = apply_filters( 'the_title', wc_attribute_label( $args['attribute'] ) );

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**OR** you can use `singular_name` instead of `name` like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'filter_dropdown_variation_args', 10 );
function filter_dropdown_variation_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_option_none'] = apply_filters( 'the_title', get_taxonomy( $args['attribute'] )->labels->singular_name );

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.